# How to deploy SPFx web parts on SP 2016 on prem?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, deployment, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am working on a development environment on SP 2016 on prem with feature pack 2. I have created a "Hello world" web part following [this example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part). I am trying to deploy the SPFx web part to a classic on prem page, so I created the app catalog where I added the .sppkg - file. 
I managed to add the web part to the classic page by using the ribbon, but the web part only works when I am running "gulp - serve" in the background on the project. Is it suppoed to be like this? I thought adding the web part to the catalog should do the trick for me.

If I have to deploy the SPFx-web parts the oldschool way, like in this sample, I will be very dissapointed: 
https://rasper87.wordpress.com/2018/04/24/provision-spfx-web-parts-to-classic-sites-part-1-include-spfx-assets-package-inside-wsp/

> It is very easy to get confused with all the documentation and samples
>   out there with add-ins, app catalog, developer site, apps and then SPFx online and on prem.

Answer (score 8):

Please see [SharePoint Framework development with SharePoint 2016 Feature Pack 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)

In particular, see the section on deployment.

[image: Hosting your solution]

Make sure to heed the part about removing the restriction on .json files being uploaded if you are going to host your JavaScript files in SharePoint.

Here are the steps I used to deploy a SharePoint Framework web part named Hello World to SharePoint 2016. In this case I chose to host the JavaScript files in SharePoint.

I removed the block on uploading .json files in the web application.

[image: Blocked files]

I created a new document library named CDN and then a folder named Hello World inside that document library.

I set the cndBasePath property in the `write-manifests.json` file in my web part project to point to this document library.

[image: write-manifests]

After running `gulp bundle --ship` I copied the files in the `temp/deploy` folder of my web part project to the Hello World folder in the CDN document library.

[image: JavaScript files in project]

[image: JavaScript files in SharePoint]

Finally I added my Hello World web part to a SharePoint 2016 web part page.

[image: Running web part]

Comment: Hi Rob, and thanks for the answer. I unblocked .json filetype, created a document library called CDN on my intranet root site collection where I copied the files from temp/deploy (after running gulp bundle --ship), and added the app to the app catalog site collection. I had set the "cdnBasePath": "http://dev.intranett.no/CDN". I still get error.

Comment: The eror is: 
 Error loading https://component-id.invalid/91425d5b-7f80-4763-94a3-2b7bf02b3ba5_0.0.1
 https://component-id.invalid/91425d5b-7f80-4763-94a3-2b7bf02b3ba5_0.0.1 did not call System.register or AMD define. If loading a global module configure the global name via the meta exports property for script injection support.
   at Anonymous function (" dev.intranett.imdi.no /_layouts/15/next/spfx /sp-classic-page-assembly_nb-no.js ?version=1:507:105789")
   at q ("http://dev.intranett.no/_layouts/15/next/spfx/sp-classic-page-assembly_nb-no.js ? version=1:8:2379")